# Jquery Dialog box within php grid

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jquery dialogbox for each returned records from the mysql query.  But when only the first one works and the rest do nothing.

Is it possible to use the dialog box for each record and let's say to bring up their details for editing?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code. And elaborate what exactly "the rest do nothing" means.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php) plugin + ajax calls to do the same. You may find this Jquery plug-in useful.